# java persistence works with reading from database,fails to insert / update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, spring-transactions

**hi guys i m new to Hibernate and JPA.
This is my VO class.**

**Product.java**

```
package com.sample.myproduct.valueobject;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.sample.myproduct.constants.MyproductConstants;


@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@NamedQuery( 
          name=MyproductConstants.PRODUCT_NAMED_QUERY, 
          query=MyproductConstants.SELECT_QUERY_PRODUCT
        )
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Product_id")
    int productId;

    @Column(name="Name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="Desc")
    String desc;

    @Column(name="Rating")
    int rating;

    @Column(name="stock")
    int stock;

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }   
}
```

**Impl Class**

```
package com.sample.myproduct.servicedao;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sample.myproduct.constants.MyproductConstants;
import com.sample.myproduct.valueobject.Product;

@Transactional
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManagerFactory;

    public EntityManager getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManager entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public void save(Product product){
        entityManagerFactory.persist(product);
    }

    public Product getProductById(int id) throws DataAccessException{
        return entityManagerFactory.find(Product.class,id);
    }

}

}
```

**persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"

    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.sample.myproduct.servicedao.ProductDAOImpl</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.myproduct" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb" p:username="root" p:password="" />

    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sample.myproduct" />
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
            <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans:bean id="productService"
        class="com.sample.myproduct.servicebo.ProductService">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="productDAO" class="com.sample.myproduct.servicedao.ProductDAOImpl"></beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**I am able to read data from db but not able to insert data..its not giving any exception.when i added entityManager.flush() after persist function;.
its giving exception as no transaction is in progress
I am not able to find solution for this..**

Answer (score 0):

When using JpaTransactionManager, you should specify the dialect as well as below.

```
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
   <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>
```

### Update:

No transaction is required to read data from database but active transaction is required to write data to database.

If you don't configure the transactionManager correctly, @Transaction annotation will be ignored silently and all your operation will run as if no transaction is available; therefore, your write operation will fail.

Comment: 'INFO : com.sample.myproduct.servicebo.ProductService - ---->addProduct in ProductBO
INFO : com.sample.myproduct.servicebo.ProductService - <----addProduct in ProductBO'    **problem exits** its going inside the save function block coming out but writing data into DB

Comment: I'm just thinking what else could be wrong. Would you try changing the transactionManager from JpaTransactionManager to DataSourceTransactionManager as below <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

Comment: <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> when i removed mode entry.its trying to insert..i m getting follwing exception..**RROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc, Name, Rating, stock, Product_id) values ('hjjghvgcfcv', 'Razak', 5, 3, 50)' at line 1**

Comment: ok good. Cross verify whether your entity has correct table name and column names.